# Running buildbot behind cherokee reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, buildbot, cherokee

I am attempting to run my buildbot master server behind a cherokee reverse proxy with the buildbot instance as cherokee's information source in a round robin reverse proxy layout.

This is the buildbot master.cfg configuration file:-

```
# -*- python -*-
# ex: set syntax=python:

# This is a sample buildmaster config file. It must be installed as
# 'master.cfg' in your buildmaster's base directory.

# This is the dictionary that the buildmaster pays attention to. We also use
# a shorter alias to save typing.
c = BuildmasterConfig = {}

####### BUILDSLAVES

# The 'slaves' list defines the set of recognized buildslaves. Each element is
# a BuildSlave object, specifying a unique slave name and password.  The same
# slave name and password must be configured on the slave.
from buildbot.buildslave import BuildSlave
c['slaves'] = [BuildSlave("example-slave", "pass")]

# 'slavePortnum' defines the TCP port to listen on for connections from slaves.
# This must match the value configured into the buildslaves (with their
# --master option)
c['slavePortnum'] = 9989

####### CHANGESOURCES

# the 'change_source' setting tells the buildmaster how it should find out
# about source code changes.  Here we point to the buildbot clone of pyflakes.

from buildbot.changes.gitpoller import GitPoller
c['change_source'] = []
c['change_source'].append(GitPoller(
        'git://github.com/buildbot/pyflakes.git',
        workdir='gitpoller-workdir', branch='master',
        pollinterval=300))

####### SCHEDULERS

# Configure the Schedulers, which decide how to react to incoming changes.  In this
# case, just kick off a 'runtests' build

from buildbot.schedulers.basic import SingleBranchScheduler
from buildbot.schedulers.forcesched import ForceScheduler
from buildbot.changes import filter
c['schedulers'] = []
c['schedulers'].append(SingleBranchScheduler(
                            name="all",
                            change_filter=filter.ChangeFilter(branch='master'),
                            treeStableTimer=None,
                            builderNames=["runtests"]))
c['schedulers'].append(ForceScheduler(
                            name="force",
                            builderNames=["runtests"]))

####### BUILDERS

# The 'builders' list defines the Builders, which tell Buildbot how to perform a build:
# what steps, and which slaves can execute them.  Note that any particular build will
# only take place on one slave.

from buildbot.process.factory import BuildFactory
from buildbot.steps.source import Git
from buildbot.steps.shell import ShellCommand

factory = BuildFactory()
# check out the source
factory.addStep(Git(repourl='git://github.com/buildbot/pyflakes.git', mode='copy'))
# run the tests (note that this will require that 'trial' is installed)
factory.addStep(ShellCommand(command=["trial", "pyflakes"]))

from buildbot.config import BuilderConfig

c['builders'] = []
c['builders'].append(
    BuilderConfig(name="runtests",
      slavenames=["example-slave"],
      factory=factory))

####### STATUS TARGETS

# 'status' is a list of Status Targets. The results of each build will be
# pushed to these targets. buildbot/status/*.py has a variety to choose from,
# including web pages, email senders, and IRC bots.

c['status'] = []

from buildbot.status import html
from buildbot.status.web import authz, auth

authz_cfg=authz.Authz(
    # change any of these to True to enable; see the manual for more
    # options
    auth=auth.BasicAuth([("pyflakes","pyflakes")]),
    gracefulShutdown = False,
    forceBuild = 'auth', # use this to test your slave once it is set up
    forceAllBuilds = False,
    pingBuilder = False,
    stopBuild = False,
    stopAllBuilds = False,
    cancelPendingBuild = False,
)
c['status'].append(html.WebStatus(http_port=8010, authz=authz_cfg))

####### PROJECT IDENTITY

# the 'title' string will appear at the top of this buildbot
# installation's html.WebStatus home page (linked to the
# 'titleURL') and is embedded in the title of the waterfall HTML page.

c['title'] = "Pyflakes"
c['titleURL'] = "http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodPyflakes"

# the 'buildbotURL' string should point to the location where the buildbot's
# internal web server (usually the html.WebStatus page) is visible. This
# typically uses the port number set in the Waterfall 'status' entry, but
# with an externally-visible host name which the buildbot cannot figure out
# without some help.

c['buildbotURL'] = "http://localhost:8010/"

####### DB URL

c['db'] = {
    # This specifies what database buildbot uses to store its state.  You can leave
    # this at its default for all but the largest installations.
    'db_url' : "sqlite:///state.sqlite",
}
    # change any of these to True to enable; see the manual for more
    # options
    auth=auth.BasicAuth([("pyflakes","pyflakes")]),
```

And this is the cherokee configuration:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, I get `502 Bad gateway` when I go to my web url but on the other hand, I know that my buildbot master server instance is working correctly because going to the same web url and appending `:8010` behind the web url gives me the "Welcome to the Buildbot ..." page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your proxy on the same machine as the buildbot? If not, you will need to adjust the URL in cherokee, to point to the machine running buildbot (localhost points to the machine cherokee is running on).

In any case, `c['buildbotURL']` should be changed to point to the public URL that the buildbot is available under (i.e. what cherokee exposes, rather than the URL being proxied).